# How to use a text file containing a list of words as a drop down menu for html?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, text-files

I am trying to create a drop down menu in an ASP.NET using a text file as the list elements.  I want to create the menu from the text file so I can easily add or delete different options without adding the ASP.NET source code.  Also, how could I store new options as variables in ASP.NET when more options are added to the text file?  My code-behind is c#.
Thanks all,
Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't actually created the text file yet, I would suggest creating an XML text file for this, then using LINQ to XML to pull the values out, and bind them to your dropdown.

Search on those keywords to find the details on how to do those things.

your XML file might look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dropDownValues>
    <entry>
        <text>Dog</text>
        <value>1</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <text>Cat</text>
        <value>2</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <text>Canary</text>
        <value>3</value>
    </entry>
</dropDownValues>
```

Then query the data like this:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(pathToXmlDocument);

// Return an "anonymous" type that represents your XML document:
var dropDownValues = xDoc.Descendants("entry")
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Text = x.Element("text").Value,
        Value = x.Element("value").Value
    });
```

Then bind to your drop down:

```
myDropDown.DataSource = dropDownValues;
myDropDown.DataTextField = "Text";
myDropDown.DataValueField = "Value";
myDropDown.DataBind();
```

Comment: No prob. I do think using XML in this scenario is desirable, as it will help you better represent the format of this data (better than a plain text file anyway). This is really the purpose of XML: it is a "data description language"

Answer (score 2):

you can do this several ways.. lets say you have a file with a list of items named menuItems.txt you could do something like this 
if the list were like this for example

```
  Open
  SaveAs
  Save
  Exit ....ect you get the drift

List<string> lstMenuItems = 
new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines(strFilePath+ menuItems.txt));//make this a variable.
```

this will read all the items in a list and then from there you could Create the MenuItem object and load the ites from the lstMenuItems